# How to add HTTP2 to jetty server?

Tags: java, clojure, server, jetty, http2

I use clojure. I try this command:

java -Dport=4334 -Dadd-to-start=http2  -jar target/app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

But it's doesn`t work.
My main function is:

```
(defn -main [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port (env :port) 5000))]
    (run-jetty (site #'app) {:port port :join? false})))
```

Comment: What precisely are you trying to accomplish with this command? What is the expected result you'd like to see?

Comment: @brightmatrix I try to enable http2 protocol for jetty server.

Comment: Have you tried using the ring-jetty9-adapter and using the [http2 example](https://github.com/sunng87/ring-jetty9-adapter/blob/master/examples/rj9a/http2.clj)?

Comment: @CurtisSummers when i use ring-jetty9-adapter and exclude adapter from other library like ring, lib-noir,where needs ring, every time i have errors like this :

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate ring/adapter/jetty__init.class"

dependency hell.